# How to type cast an Enum to a Double in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums, codable, equatable

I have a codable Enum, that can take the form of a string OR a double because the JSON response I get can either be in a string or a double. I need to extract the double from the enum but I can't figure out why.

```
enum greeksEnum: Codable, Equatable
{
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        
    }
    
    case double(Double), string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        if let double = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Double.self)
        {
            self = .double(double)
            return
        }
    
        if let string = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
        {
            self = .string(string)
            return
        }
    
        throw greekError.missingValue
    }
    

    enum greekError:Error
    {
        case missingValue
    }
}
```

How would I be able to extract the double value into a double variable?

This is how I compare the strings:

```
 if (volatility[0] == optionsApp.ExpDateMap.greeksEnum.string("NaN"))
 {
 }
```

But when I try to type cast the enum to a type Double I get this error.

```
self.IV = Double(volatility[0])
```

Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'ExpDateMap.greeksEnum' conform to 'BinaryInteger'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `switch` operator to check the case of your enum and extract its associated value:

```swift
let x: GreeksEnum = .double(3.14)

switch x {
case .double(let doubleValue):
    print("x is a double: \(doubleValue)")
case .string(let stringValue):
    print("x is a string: \(stringValue)")
}
```

If you only need one case and not all of them, use `if-case-let` or `guard-case-let`:

```swift
if case .double(let doubleValue) = x {
    print("x is a double: \(doubleValue)")
}
```

Tip: Always name your types in CapitalizedWords (i.e. `GreeksEnum` and `GreekError` rather than `greeksEnum` and `greekError`, that is a common standard in Swift).

Comment: Thank you! I'm coming from a C OS programmer side, so I need to change how I write my naming of variables.